# Was Ashford v Thornton heard at the Royal courts of Justice in Chancery Lane, London or elsewhere?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, legal-history, murder, appeal

What physical venue was this 19th century Murder appeal heard in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appeal in [Ashford v Thornton (1818) 1 B. & Ald. 405, 106 ER 149](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashford_v_Thornton) was before the Court of King's Bench. In 1818, this court that had not yet been merged into the High Court of Justice - that would happen [in 1875](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_Judicature_Act_1873). It never sat in the [Royal Courts of Justice building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Courts_of_Justice), because that was built at the later date of 1882.

The cited case would have been heard in Westminster Hall, the normal home of the Court of King's Bench since 1318. It shared this site with other important courts - the Courts of Chancery, Common Pleas and the Exchequer. The Hall is part of the Palace of Westminster, and is one of the few parts of the complex not destroyed by fire in 1834. It's mainly used now as a spare debating chamber and for certain public and state events.